# Extending underline up to the right side

Tags: text-decorations, soul

I need to create command that underlines some given text that takes several lines. And the underline of the last line should be extended up to the right side of page. When I need just to underline multiline text I use `\ul` from `soul` package. But I couldn't find any trick to extend last line. Something like `\ul{Last line\hfill\mbox{}}` gives nothing. Using `\soulregister{\hfill}{0}` doesn't help, too. Even if I force line break, `\hfill` will be ignored, i.e. `\ul{Last line\hfill\mbox{}\linebreak}` gives line with huge space between `Last` and `line` and no space after `line`. The only way to get something close to desired that I've found is the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\raisedrule}[1]{\leaders\hbox{\rule[#1]{1pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill}
\newcommand{\longunderline}[1]{\ul{#1}\raisedrule{-3.5pt}\mbox{}}
\soulregister{\hfill}{0}

\begin{document}
    \longunderline{Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.}

    \longunderline{Some short text.}

    \ul{Oh, \hfill.}
\end{document}
```

However height of raise of rule may depend on text and there is some break between underline and rule after text. So my solution is really bad. Do you see something better?

More complex case when I need to make exact number of undelined lines, supposing that text is always short enough to fit into desired number of lines, but not always long enough, i.e. some lines may be completely blank. Any idea?

**EDIT**

Using `ulem` and `\uline` instead of `soul` and `\ul` allows to “underline” `\hfill`. However it gives new problem loosing hyphenation. More interesting that it is possible to “help” it to make hyphen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{ulem}

\pagestyle{empty}
\soulregister{\hfill}{0}

\begin{document}
    \uline{Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Somelongword. Some long text.\hfill}

    \uline{Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Somelong\-word. Some long text.\hfill}

    \ul{Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Somelongword. Some long text.\hfill}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Middle version is what I want to get, but now it is needed to allow hyphen by hand.

**EDIT 2**

One more example. Here `\uline` makes overfull while `\ul` does not make neither overfull nor underfull.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
    \Huge
    \ul{Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.}

    \uline{Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although, `\ul{...Last Line \hfill something}` gives interesting results.

Comment: The same as `\ul{Oh, \hfill.}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{linegoal}


\newcommand{\raisedrule}[1]{\rule[#1]{\linegoal}{0.45pt}}
\newcommand{\longunderline}[1]{\ul{#1}\raisedrule{-.75ex}}

\begin{document}
    \longunderline{Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.}

    \longunderline{Some short text.}

    \longunderline{Oh,.}

    \longunderline{Last line}

    \longunderline{Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Somelongword. Some long text.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This takes at least two compilation runs.

Comment: Looks very well, thank you! But how did you get `0.45pt` value? It becomes too thin for `\Huge` font. However `\SOUL@ulthickness` equals to `0.1ex` by default and this value is always good.

Comment: @Smylic hehe. I eye balled. Adjust the values as you need please. Please remember that dimensions in `pt` will be fixed with font change. Use either in `ex` or `em`.

Comment: BTW default line thickness in `ulem` is `0.4pt`.

Comment: @Smylic One can convert `ex` in to `pt` and vice versa. There is an answer in the site for that. In fact you can use `\SOUL@ulthickness` itself so that it changes dynamically. Similarly for `raisebox...`

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind to use the [`ulem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem) package instead of `soul`, this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand{\longunderline}[1]{\uline{#1\hfill\mbox{}}}

\begin{document}
    \longunderline{Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.}

    \longunderline{Some short text.}

    \longunderline{Oh.}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I should check it myself. However this solution is not perfect, because it looses hyphenation. See `\longunderline{Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Somelongword. Some long text.}`. `\ul` makes hyphen, `\uline` gives overfull. The most interesting that specifying possible hyphenation by `\-` makes sense for `\uline`.